# How to enter a non-breaking space on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, internationalization, space

On a Mac, entering a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) is very easy. On my iPad with iOS 7 installed, I want to enter a non-breaking space. But I find no way.

I have tried the mic on the keyboard. It gives me this :

`Espace insécable`

:-)

I would prefer a solution coming from the keyboard. I would also like a palette offering characters or snippets.

Comment: In which application do you want to enter a non-breaking space character?

Comment: @patrix — Usually, Safari.

Comment: You should be able to copy paste any character from apps like Unicode Map, and also create a keyboard shortcut to create this character by typing something else.

Comment: @Tom — I like the idea of a keyboard shortcut. How could I create one?

Comment: See if this helps:  http://ipad.about.com/od/ipad_basics/ss/Ipad-Keyboard-Settings-Help_3.htm

Comment: @Tom — Very good idea, thank you ! Well, it's a bit tricky. First, a non-breaking space alone is not accepted as the content of a shortcut. So I chose " ?" Then the shortcut is not proposed in all cases. But I chose the shortcut ",s" and it is proposed in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

Find one in a web page (even a page you create yourself, inserting  ) and then copy it to the clipboard. Paste it in when needed.

Comment: This is what I do.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson — In what application do you do the copy?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco  Any text application should work -- Notes, Pages, etc.  Are you having a problem with it?

Comment: This didn’t work for me :(

Answer (score 2):

In my jailbroken iPhone4 with iOS 7.1.2 I have installed `Persian Keyboard iOS5+` from the `BigBoss` repository in Cydia. For my native language `Farsi`, this keyboard has non-breaking space near the Space button.

In the image below I have typed the translation of the `non-breaking space` in Farsi `نیم‌فاصله` which the correct form is the last line with non-breaking space between ‍`نیم` and `فاصله`. The middle line has normal space and the first line has no space.

[image]

If your device is jailbroken maybe there are alternatives for the keyboard in the Cydia repository for your preferred language.

Comment: While I can't jailbreak the device in question, I don't think the answer deserves a downvote! +1.

Comment: Thank you. But I would prefer a solution without jailbreak. Do you know one?

Comment: I think that, on the image, space is missing at the place of the non-breaking space. What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit convoluted, so hopefully someone comes up with [a lot] better. On your Mac, create a note with a non breaking space (option+spacebar on Mac) in a known position. Now open that note, select that non breaking space (I found that tricky), & copy it. Go to Settings > General > Keyboards > Text Replacement. Tap the + at the top right, paste the non breaking space as the Phrase, & something as the Shortcut (I used `nbsp`). When you use it you need to type a space before typing your shortcut, & iOS will insert a space after you select the phrase. That's a regular space either side of your non breaking space that you need to delete.

Comment: I’ve used this trick to get around needing a different keyboard. Super handy general trick that solves this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

For a palette with all Unicode characters, try [Unicode Pad](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/unicode-pad/id374098312?mt=8).

Comment: Thank you Tom. But it is not free, and it is an app, its characters are not available in the keyboard in the app I am in.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to setup a keyboard replacement text mapping “&nbxp;” to a non-breaking space, which I copypasted from a Numbers spreadsheet originally created under MacOSX. Note I had to substitute “nbxp” for “nbsp” because stackexchange seems to interpret the HTML code! Probably a bug.

Here it is if you need it “ “.

[addendum: OMG I copypasted the character between the “ quotes above back into my Numbers test rig, and for all the world it looks like the nonbreaking space made it through! So if you’re trying to setup this trick on your iPad try pasting the thing between the double quotes into the replacement text field in the Settings->General->Keyboard->Text Replacement->+->Phrase field.]

Comment: Thank you Charles

Comment: Really ? On what system ? My iPad mini and an iPhone refuse that a replacement text be a non-breaking space.

Answer (score -2):

If you hold the zero on you iOS keyboard you should see the little superscript circle (degree symbol)

°

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The OP is asking for a way to print a non-breaking space, that is, a space that prevents an automatic line break at its position. How is the  `⁰` character related to that?

Comment: Did you perhaps intend to answer a different question and got here by mistake?  You should delete it here, as it makes no sense.

Comment: I don’t want a degree symbol, I want a non-breaking space.